# NFS mount - access denied on Ubuntu but mounts ok on CentOS

Tags: mount, nfs

I'm running some NFS mount tests this morning and getting some weird results: CentOS will mount, Ubuntu will not. Same commands are issued - is there something special i need to do on Ubuntu?

```
mount –t nfs 10.250.1.5:/Vol003 /mnt/db
```

- Centos

  [image: Centos-OK]
- Ubuntu

  [image: Ubuntu-Failed]

Any ideas? Disclaimer - newbie to linux and netapp - any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is an issue with my base Ubuntu Image - deployed and AWS Ubuntu AMI and the NFS mount command worked.......

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have, you allowed access from the IP your CentOS is on but the Ubuntu host doesn't have access.

Control your `/etc/exports` and adjust them accordingly.

Comment: The export policy on the Netapp array had the IPs of both the Ubuntu and Centos Servers. I even changed the export policy to 0.0.0.0/0 and ran into the same issue.

Comment: Some more testing this morning with different options and the following worked on my image (14.04) `-o v3` . This isnt needed on my test image in AWS (16.04)

Comment: For this kind of things always look into the syslog of the machine you are trying to connect to, it usually tells you exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

On the 14.04 Ubuntu Image, I needed to add the `-o v3` option and it mounted. This wasn't required for my 16.04 image